# How to animate scroll down/up event?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to animate scroll down/up in JQuery like this site: [union.co](http://union.co/)

and prevent several animate/event

I used this code, but it works only first time :

```
var lastScrollTop = 0;
$(window).scroll(function (event) {
    var st = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (st > lastScrollTop) {
        $(window).scrollTop("#div1");
    } else {
        $(window).scrollTop("#div0");
    }
    lastScrollTop = st;
});
```

Comment: You can easily achieve that by using [fullPage.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/) plugin.

Answer (score 0):

maybe part of this would help:

```
var i;
$(window).scroll(function (event) {
    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $('#myid1').offset().top }, 500);
    i++
});
```

find how to use variable in id , and name id in every 'screen' .

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of plugins that you can use to achieve what you are looking for. I used to work with [onepage-scroll](https://github.com/peachananr/onepage-scroll), before using my own plugin.

In the [site](http://union.co/) that you are giving as an example, they are using [bxslider](http://bxslider.com/), a responsive jQuery content slider. It does not do exactly what you are asking for. It's only a content slider. You have to add some more few lines to be able to scroll by page.

The [fullPage.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/) plugin proposed by [Alvaro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1081396/alvaro) is also a very good plugin. Besides, it supports window redimensioning.

Choose one plugin. The documentation is very clear. If you face any problem, let me know. I'll be pleased to help.

Hope it's useful!